# VB.Net how to export codes of or exact Stored Procedures of MSSQL 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, export-to-text

Is it possible to get that whole stored procedure codes and save it to a text file?

- I would like to create a program in VB.net where the user will just have to click a button then save/extract all the procedures that have been altered or newly created on that day for backup purposes.
- I can already check those dates using this query..

  ```
  SELECT name, create_date, modify_date FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P'
  ```
- I would like to get the whole codes.. **not the result** of that stored procedure.
- I know it can be done in mssql tasks but I want the other way around..

Comment: if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`OBJECT_DEFINITION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) function:

```
SELECT name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM sys.procedures
```

btw, a simple google search (get stored procedure text sql server) got me this [link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx#TsqlProcedure) You should have googled first.

Comment: Already tried googling it but I always ended up in getting "how to get the result" of the stored procedures. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes you just need to know the search keywords... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for getting modified list
SELECT 
    name,
    create_date,
    modify_date
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE create_date = dynamicdate()

to get text of stored preocedure

SELECT text FROM syscomments WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'spname'

and iterate the first result then pass sp name to second script
```